# Migration from RC4 to AES256 Kerberos problems - Tomcat 9.0.64

Tags: java, tomcat, kerberos

Hi I tried to migrate our Java application from RC4 to AES256 encryption by generating new keytab.

To generate keytab I used ktutil:

```
addent -password -p HTTP/my.host@MY.DOMAIN -k 1 -e aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96
```

For user I have changed parameter type to:
`msds-supportedEncryptionType = 24 (0x18)`

and set SPN to `HTTP/my.host@MY.DOMAIN`

Also changed in krb5.conf to:

```
        default_tkt_enctypes = aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96 aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96
        default_tgs_enctypes = aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96 aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96
        permitted_enctypes = aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96 aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96
```

For kerberos logs I am using following parameters:
`-Dsun.security.krb5.debug=true -Dsun.security.jgss.debug=true -Dsun.security.spnego.debug=true`

Unfortunately I am getting 401 error with Windows authentication box appearing.

In code I get following logs:

```
Debug is true storeKey true useTicketCache false useKeyTab true doNotPrompt true ticketCache is null isInitiator false KeyTab is /location/tomcat/base/conf/kerberos.keytab refreshKrb5Config is false principal is HTTP/my.host@MY.DOMAIN tryFirstPass is false useFirstPass is false storePass is false clearPass is false
principal is HTTP/my.host@MY.DOMAIN
Will use keytab
Commit Succeeded
Search Subject for SPNEGO ACCEPT cred (<<DEF>>, sun.security.jgss.spnego.SpNegoCredElement)
Search Subject for Kerberos V5 ACCEPT cred (<<DEF>>, sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5AcceptCredential)
Found KeyTab /location/tomcat/base/conf/kerberos.keytab for HTTP/my.host@MY.DOMAIN
Found KeyTab /location/tomcat/base/conf/kerberos.keytab for HTTP/my.host@MY.DOMAIN
Entered SpNegoContext.acceptSecContext with state=STATE_NEW
SpNegoContext.acceptSecContext: receiving token = a0 82 08 b7 30 82 08 b3 a0 30 30 2e 06 09 2a 86 48 ...
SpNegoToken NegTokenInit: reading Mechanism Oid = 1.2.840.113554.1.2.2
SpNegoToken NegTokenInit: reading Mechanism Oid = 1.2.840.48018.1.2.2
SpNegoToken NegTokenInit: reading Mechanism Oid = 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.2.30
SpNegoToken NegTokenInit: reading Mechanism Oid = 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.2.10
SpNegoToken NegTokenInit: reading Mech Token
SpNegoContext.acceptSecContext: received token of type = SPNEGO NegTokenInit
SpNegoContext: negotiated mechanism = 1.2.840.113554.1.2.2
Entered Krb5Context.acceptSecContext with state=STATE_NEW
Looking for keys for: HTTP/my.host@MY.DOMAIN
Added key: 18version: 1
>>> EType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.Aes256CtsHmacSha1EType
[Krb5LoginModule]: Entering logout
[Krb5LoginModule]: logged out Subject
```

As you see above after adding key it entering logout. Unfortunately I don't get any error here and it not clear for me why it is not working.
Previously with RC4 encoding it was working correctly.

Tomcat: 9.0.64
Java: 1.8.0_322-b06

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you had RC4, I *suspect* you're using Active Directory as your Kerberos KDC.

While Kerberos RC4-HMAC keys were completely unsalted (they were literally an NT-style MD4 hash), the AES128 or AES256 keys *do* use a salt as part of the (new) PBKDF2 key derivation.

In "standard" MIT Kerberos, the salt is based directly on the principal name, i.e. `HTTP/my.host` is converted to the salt. However, that's not the case with Active Directory, where a single account could have multiple SPNs while sharing a single key between them – instead, AD creates the salt based on the account's "sAMAccountName" (which is probably something like `tomcat123`).

The most likely result here is that the keys derived by ktutil don't match keys derived by your AD DC because of the mismatching salts. To fix this, use the **`addent -f`** option to make ktutil *ask the KDC* about what salt to use (the same way as would be done during 'kinit' or other ticket acquisition).